# Zend Framework issue in run command in netbeans

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans

I am trying my hands on using Zend framework with netbeans.

I have setup everything correctly as i can create project using ZF command line and can create other controller and actions.

But when i setup project in netbeans and use run command it does not seems to understand Zend framework MVC url structure and shows complete path in browser.

instead of running http://testing.com/about

it is taking http://testing.com/application/controllers/AboutController.php

but when i type is manually everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need adjust a few settings in your project properties. Open your project properties menu and select `Sources` make sure your `Web Root` is set to `public`, while you're there make sure your sources and project folder are correct.

Next select `Run Configuration` and make sure your `Project URL` is correct. When using ZF there is no need to specify an index file, netbeans may complain some but it will work.

Now when want to run your project you have to run the whole project. When using ZF you can't run just one file because all request are routed through the `index.php` in the public folder. So Always select run at the project level and not at the file level.

Comment: Thanks RockyFord for your answer.